# Arduino Uno - Max Sensors

Tags: arduino, sensors

I'm looking for some information on Arduino and UltraSonic Sensors. I'm considering getting the following [Arduino Uno board](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9950) for templating the basics of an installation piece.

I'm getting started with this I was wondering if anyone could tell me what the maximum amount of [sensors](http://www.robotgear.com.au/Product.aspx/Details/285) it would be able to connect at any one time?

Comment: Wrong forum, dude. But the answer is "lots".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the documentation you link to http://www.robotgear.com.au/Product.aspx/Details/285 you can add 16 of these on one I2C or serial port.

By default you have 1 standard i2c bus on the arduino.

You will have to be careful because these devices can interfere with each other, one can pick up the echo of another and so keep in mind when you measure using on sensor not to start a second measure with an other sensor (that could pickup the return of the first) before the first measurement is finisched or has timed out

Comment: I think we're going to be iterating through them linearly so I'll be sure to add a sizable delay to not get false reads. Awesome cheers for the heads up.